# Unable to authenticate rest call through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, postman

I have been using postman to test an API which, I am successfully able to call.

When I try to execute this call through javascript I get an authentication error.

The URL and authorization match that of the postman call and when I call using these details with curl I am able to retrieve the correct data.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var data = new FormData();
data.append("attributeId", "");
data.append("validFrom", "");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http:/restpAPI/test");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic asdsadsadjlafdkfjkldfj==");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "dsadasd-asdsad-asd-asd-aasd");
xhr.send(data);


  </script>
```

When I run a local web page with this script I get a 401 saying Unauthorized.

What is the difference between the JavaScript code and postman or cURL and is there a way of authenticating from JavaScript?

**Update**

I have discovered that setting the RequestHeader with the authorization key turns the request from a get to an options. This is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Although HTTP Headers are supposed to be case insensitive, have you tried setting the headers' names with title case (`Authorization`)?